# How to disable Create button to prevent multiple times the data to be saved in database in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a model District. For creating a new district record, I enter district name in text box and click on Create button. The district record gets created. Now while creating if I click many times the create button, then multiple times the data gets saved. I want to disable the Create button after successful validation in yii2, so that it can prevent multiple submission.

Comment: If your using the activeForm widget, faryshta/yii2-disable-submit-buttons extension is great. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Yii2 plugin for the task

https://github.com/Faryshta/yii2-disable-submit-buttons

Comment: Excellent choice! I saw a few posts stating to upgrade to 2.0.10, but that did not work for me. I implemented this extension, it works great with the active form widget.

Answer (score 0):

In the beforeSubmit event of ActiveForm js.

Inside the view file:

```
$this->registerJs("
    $('#form').on('beforeSubmit', function (e) {
        $('#submitButton').css('disable', 'disable');
        return true;
    });
");
```

Considering #form as form id and submitButton as submit button id.

Comment: I tried the code, but it doesnt works. The create button is still enabled. Do I need to put this code in script tag?

Comment: Yes, you have to register the code, using registerJs inside the view file.